# Excel AddIn with custom context menu that worked well in 2010+Win7 doesn't work in 2013+Win10

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, add-in

Long time ago I made small AddIn for Excel to upload small trunks off data to SQL server. Quite simple form is called from context menu on right btn mouse click. It worked well on Win7 + Excel 2010 (don't know if OS is important). Recently I moved to Win10 + Excel 2013. And the context menu won't show up anymore... Well actually I can make it show but only once. My ThisAddIn_Startup

```
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        logger.Info("Started");
        CreateContextMenu();
        Application.SheetBeforeRightClick += Application_SheetBeforeRightClick; 
    }
```

And here's CreateContextMenu

```
    private void CreateContextMenu()
    {
        try
        {
            Office.MsoControlType menuItem = Office.MsoControlType.msoControlButton;
            uploadToDatabase = (Office.CommandBarButton)Application.CommandBars["Cell"].
                Controls.Add(menuItem, missing, missing, 1, true);
            uploadToDatabase.Style = Office.MsoButtonStyle.msoButtonCaption;
            uploadToDatabase.Caption = "Upload to database";
            uploadToDatabase.Tag = "0";

            //MessageBox.Show("MF");
            logger.Info("Added context menu");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error(ex);
        }
    }
```

In log file I see both records - "Started" and "Added context menu", but context menu is still not customized.
But if I uncomment the line `MessageBox.Show("MF");` then it will show up for the first start of excel and then again dissappear if I close a workbook and open any other.

Does anyone have an idea why?

Appreciate for any hints.

Comment: Okay, I managed to fix the AddIn by moving CreateContextMenu() into Application_SheetBeforeRightClick and slightly customizing the method by adding flag contextMenuCreated (to prevent duplication), but the question is still open...

Comment: I've created a context menu in the XML ribbon before if that helps. [Context Menu](https://github.com/Excel-projects/Script-Help/blob/master/CS/Ribbon.xml#L665-L839)

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that Command bars are not used any longer (were deprecated). The only possible way to customize the context menus in Office 2013 and later versions is to use the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI). You can read more about that in the following articles in MSDN:

- [Customizing Context Menus in Office 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee691832%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)